# Let $u(x,y)=x^{3}+ax^{2}y+bxy^{2}+2y^{3}$ be a harmonic function, $v(x,y)$ be its harmonic conjugate....

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, harmonic-functions, analytic-functions

> Let $u(x,y)=x^{3}+ax^{2}y+bxy^{2}+2y^{3}$ be a harmonic function and
>   $v(x,y)$ be its harmonic conjugate. If $v(0,0)= 1$, then find
>   $|a+b+v(1,1)|$.

**For finding $a$ and $b$**

Let $u(x,y)=x^{3}+ax^{2}y+bxy^{2}+2y^{3}$ be a ***harmonic function*** , then it satisfy **Laplacian equation.**

From that I got,

$6x+12y+2ay+2bx=0x+0y\tag{1}.$

> Can I equate the coefficients and find $a$ and $b$? Is there any logical error?

Rest of the solution, I can do.

Comment: Solving completely also gives $a=-6$ and $b=-3$, so...

Comment: Can I do like that? Is there any error? I think it follows from linear independence. Am I right?